# FCM Notifications

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, backend

I want to send notifications to multiple device token.
While it's working fine if I am sending it to a single device token.

When I try to send to multiple devices I got an error. So, I had changed the `to` key to `registration_ids` and it's somehow working but I still get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot create property 'isCatch' on string '{"multicast_id":6699347387645145001,"success":1,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1593672479225606%772927ea772927ea"},{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}'

I am using fcm-node.

```
let token = dbCall()
for (let i =0; i < token.length ; i++){
     sendToken.push(token[i].token)
}

var message = {
            to:token[0].token,      // its working fine when i am sending to one deviceToken
            to: sendToken           // its an array of deviceToken its not working
            notification: {
                body: notificationData.message,
                title: notificationData.title,
            },
            data: {
                type: notificationData.type,
                title: notificationData.title,
                message: notificationData.message,
                designOrderId : notificationData.designOrderId,
                inboxCount: token[0].inboxCount,
            }
        };

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fcm.send(message, function(err, response) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('notifyerr----->', err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    // console.log('notifyresponse----->', response);
                    resolve(response);
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: Please provide details on the error.

Comment: I had changed the 'to' key to 'registration_ids' and it's somewhat working but  i still get this error  TypeError: Cannot create property 'isCatch' on string '{"multicast_id":6699347387645145001,"success":1,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1593672479225606%772927ea772927ea"},{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}'